# What is the best way to save an HTML form to PDF - including the values entered?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pdf, pdf-generation

I would like the user to click a button which saves the current page as PDF, however I want it to include the values they have typed into the fields. I have searched Stack and many of the answers only allow me to save the original HTML form (sans values), or are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that would be desired solution for you, but you could made template of document (current website) and inject the values from the form and compile with **handlebars**. Then use **puppeteer** to generate .pdf from that template. 
It's not the straight forward solution, but could work. I made something like that for my CV creator website. You may wish to check the code: https://github.com/Vastlaan/royalresumegenerator

I hope its helpfull